# iPhone's volume low on Bluetooth speakers

Tags: iphone, sound-volume, speakers

Anytime I connect to a Bluetooth speaker it won’t play full volume, I have the volume all the way up on my phone and the speaker but it will only play at about half the volume than other phones will when they are connected to the device.